# Laravel has() on relationship still returns empty keys

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to only return tiers that have options associated to them. My query has a `has()` method, and a query on my options, but for some reason adding `->has('tiers.options', '>', 0)` still returns options that has an empty array. What am I missing here?

```php
$buyers = Buyer::with([
    'tiers.options' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('type', 'private');
    }
])->has('tiers.options', '>', 0)->get();
```

Comment: I don't think `has()` works like that on nested relationships (`'tiers.options'`). You probably need `whereHas('tiers', function ($query){ $query->has('options', '>', 0); })` (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

How about adding whereHas query inside of 'with', for example:

```
$buyers = Buyer::with([
    'tiers' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('options', function ($query) {
            $query->where('type', 'private');
        });
    }
])->get();
```

Here 'tiers' that only have options with type private are will fetched.

Comment: This will return every `Buyer` Model, since the `whereHas()` is now filtering the `tiers` Relationship query, not the `Buyer` query...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use whereHas() instead?
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

It would be something like that if I understand correctly:

```
$buyers = Buyer::whereHas('tiers.options', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('type', 'private');
        }, '>', 0)->get();
```